# python linear search code, what’s a better example if a linear search Algorithm?

Tags: python

Having issues with this python code

```
def linerar_search(list, target):
  """ Returns the index position of the target if found, else returns None"""

for i in range(0, len(list)):
    if list[i] == target:
      return i
    return none

    def verify(index):
        if index is not None:
            print("Target found at index: ", index)
        else:
                print("Target not found in list")

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

result = linear_search(numbers, 12)
verify(result)
```

showing error in line 6

Comment: I guess you've not noticed to indentation.  verify should be outside of the for and for each function you should have the indentation.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I had to fight the indention monster.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with the code above:

1. Misspelling of variable name in line 1 - `linerar_search` instead of `linear_search`
2. `None` is the reserved keyword in python, not `none`. Trying to `return none` would throw a `NameError: name 'none' is not defined`
3. The indent for function `verify` is off but it shouldn't cause errors.

The code below runs for me:

```
def linear_search(list, target):
    """ Returns the index position of the target if found, else returns None"""
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        if list[i] == target:
            return i
        return None

def verify(index):
    if index is not None:
        print("Target found at index: ", index)
    else:
        print("Target not found in list")

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

result = linear_search(numbers, 12)
verify(result)
```

Hope this helps! :)

P.S: This seems more so like a python problem then data science. Perhaps you could have posted this question in Stackoverflow instead.